# How to set up Keycloak clients with different applications

Tags: keycloak

If I have a desktop app, a mobile app and a web app and I want to use Keycloak to manage/authenticate users using these apps.

I have read somewhere that you can use the same Keycloak client for many applications or that you can use a Keycloak client for each application.

In my use case a user uses the same username and password to log in to the 3 different application and a certain user will have the same permissions throughout all of the applications? e.g. a User will be able to have all the user related functions be available to them in all of the apps.

Thus in my use case will it be better to use 1 Keycloak client for all the applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a desktop app, mobile app and a web app, accessing the same backend, for keycloack you have just one application (realm) with 3 differents entry points (clients).

Keycloak, is just an Identity and Access Management, it does not infer your application authorization logic, so is wisely to keep it simple.
One way, is to setup a single Keycloak Client to each frontend app (desktop, web and mobile), with this you can have more control on protocols authentication and behavier, and can evolve independently. BUT, if you NEED the clients and configuration have to be the same, you can create just one keycloak client. OR you need the web, and dektop be the same, and different rules for the mobile app, so you can create 2 clients. All of this is fine becouse is part of your business logic. The point is, keycloack is highly configured to work with your application.
The roles will be returned as configured in keycloak, if the user has some role, it will be returned in all clients.

Comment: By Channel do you mean Keycloak client?

Comment: @Franco yes, sorry, usually i think what channels have access to my database. But it is keycloak client.